# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: at b.j.a.t.a

Tags: android, illegalargumentexception

It is not often that I get an error which doesn't yield any results on a google search... So I've attached a screenshot from the Console. This only showed up on the latest version of my app. What's going on here??

[image]

Comment: Classes are obfuscated. You must have maps, try to findout actual class name and method which is causing this issue.

Comment: Obfuscated, maps? Doesn't ring a bell, thinking about my code. Where should I start looking?

Comment: Whenever you create a release build, you would be obfuscating you code using proguard. So while that process you this tool provides few files which can be use to map later for debugging purposes. For example, in attached screenshot b.j.a.t.e is not meaningful for you, so using those files which generated by proguard you can find out actual class name. You should read more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913338/how-to-debug-with-obfuscated-with-proguard-applications-on-android and http://simplyadvanced.net/blog/android-how-to-decode-proguards-obfuscated-code-from-stack-trace/

Comment: Thanks that's totally new to me. So just to be clear, can I debug this information from the console still somehow or only if I add those lines to proguard and re-release it to the play store for future debugging?

Comment: If you did not added configs to create those files, yes you have to add and you need to keep those files until next release. These files are only which can help you to debug release builds, otherwise you will be in trouble like current question.

Comment: Thank you. Last question - I've uploaded the mapping file to the Console. Can I be sure it's working if the stack trace of the same version are readable now for new crashes (after uploading the mapping)

Comment: No crash would be there if you did not fixed. But benefit will be, you will get a readable crash log (actual class name and methods) so you can find root cause easily and solve that.