# How to make R8 + proguard-android-optimize.txt + Google Drive API works seamlessly?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, proguard, android-r8

This is our R8 version

Current version is: 1.4.94 (build 390954928f0db9c3b888a367f7f128ce3bbfb160 from go/r8bot (luci-r8-ci-archive-0-5g74)).

When I switch from

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

to

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

We're getting the following error.

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
    {
      "code": 403,
      "errors": [
        {
          "domain": "usageLimits",
          "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
          "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
          "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
        }
      ],
      "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
    }
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:378)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.a(HttpRequest.java:1067)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:476)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:409)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:526)
        at com.yocto.wenote.sync.Utils.searchFromGoogleDrive(Utils.java:808)
```

The crash happens at the following code

```
try {
    Drive.Files.List request = drive.files().list().setSpaces(APP_DATA_FOLDER)
            .setQ("name = '" + Utils.getWeNoteZipFileTitle() + "'")
            .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name, modifiedTime)")
            .setOrderBy("modifiedTime desc")
            .setPageSize(10);

    do {
        FileList fileList = request.execute();  // <-- This is line Utils.java:808
```

---

Take note that, the above code works 100% fine, before we're switching from `proguard-android.txt` to `proguard-android-optimize.txt`.

It seems that based on `proguard-android-optimize.txt`, R8 stripes out some important information, which causes calling to Google Drive API fails.

Anyone how to make `proguard-android-optimize.txt` work with Google Drive API?

---

### How about replace R8 with Proguard?

If I use ProGuard, version 6.0.3 by applying `android.enableR8=false` (Still using `proguard-android-optimize.txt`), there are no issue when running Google Drive API related code.

---

### My Google Drive API libs

```
// For Google Drive REST API - https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples/blob/master/drive/deprecation/app/build.gradle
implementation('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.26.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.26.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev136-1.25.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
```

### My complete proguard file

```
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
*;
}



# https://github.com/huanghaibin-dev/CalendarView
-keep class com.yocto.wenote.calendar.CustomWeekView {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
}
-keep class com.yocto.wenote.calendar.CustomMonthView {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
}
-keep class com.yocto.wenote.calendar.CustomWeekBar {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
}
-keep class com.yocto.wenote.calendar.FullscreenCustomWeekBar {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
}
-keep class com.haibin.calendarview.DefaultWeekView {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
}
-keep class com.haibin.calendarview.DefaultYearView {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
}

# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913338/how-to-debug-with-obfuscated-with-proguard-applications-on-android
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html (Producing useful obfuscated stack traces)
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable,InnerClasses



# https://github.com/bumptech/glide
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}



# Used in menu/search_toolbar_menu.xml
-keep class com.yocto.wenote.search.SearchView {
*;
}



# setHintTextTypeface & setFloatTextTypeface & setFloatTextColor
-keep class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout {
*;
}
# setHintTextTypeface & setFloatTextTypeface
-keep class com.google.android.material.internal.CollapsingTextHelper {
*;
}
# setMaxHeight & setMinimumHeight
-keep class android.widget.ImageView {
  public <methods>;
}



-keep class com.yocto.wenote.recording.RippleBackground$RippleView {
  void setScaleX(***);
  void setScaleY(***);
}



# https://github.com/zhihu/Matisse
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
-dontwarn com.bumptech.glide.**



# For Google Drive API
-dontwarn com.google.common.**
-dontwarn com.google.api.client.util.**
-keep class * extends com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson {
*;
}
-keep class com.google.api.services.drive.** {
*;
}


# VerifyError in Android 4
# https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/397
-keep class com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$Tab {
*;
}


# http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices.html#obfuscate
-keep class com.android.vending.billing.**



# https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/refs/heads/master/compatibility-faq.md
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}



# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218772/removing-log-call-using-proguard
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}



# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218772/removing-log-call-using-proguard
-assumenosideeffects class com.yocto.wenote.Utils {
    public static void trackView(...);
    public static void trackEvent(...);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Could you try the following keep rule?

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
  @com.google.api.client.util.Key <fields>;
}
```

The google api client uses the com.google.api.client.util.Key by reflection:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/setup

This seems to work for others who has reported a similar issue.

Comment: this worked for me as well! I was using minify then I had this error every time I tried to open a folder at google drive. Gladly it is solved.

Comment: MortenKJ - It worked and exactly what was needed, great find. Readers please avoid having to use wider solutions as some other have suggested like -keep class com.google.** { *;}  as it will less efficient and will not minify or obsfucate lot of google packages, Use this type of limited approach to only keep the absolutely necessary classes/members.